# Sync between GameObject and Entity in ECS

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to Update gameobject transform via Unity ECS system class and it looks like system is updating with some delay.

The Scenario is as explained, In System Class i am accessing the entity that i am interacting with and updating its position/Rotation so that it look like object is attached to controller. when i set the transform to Gameobject, Transform updation is not happening properly. its leading to object rotation continuously.

Any advice on how to keep them in Sync??